# How can I prove that $a^n + b$ is composite?

Tags: proof-verification

I need to know how could I prove that $2^{33} + 1$ is composite.

Thanks!

Comment: Start by drawing a circle. No really, what have you done so far?

Comment: Well I know that this number has to be higher than 1. I have no problem proving if a number is composite for something more simple than this, but that + 1 is confusing me. Sorry, its my first post here and thanks for your interest.

Comment: Hint: $2^{33} + 1 = 2^{33} - (-1)^{33}$. Do you remember any formula that factors $a^n - b^n$?

Comment: Is it (a^1/2n - b^1/2n)(a^1/2n + b^1/2n) ?

Comment: $2^{33}+1=3×2049×1397419$

Comment: Well this is not really accepted by my teacher as a proof:/

Answer (score 2):

HINT: BY BINOMIAL THEOROM

$2^{33}+1=(3-1)^{33}+1=(3(....)-1)+1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $2^{33}+1$  is divisible by $3$. If you are familiar with congruences, note that $2$ to an even power is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$.

I can make no useful comments about the general problem of the title. For large numbers, it is very difficult.

**Remark:** One first step in approaching the problem is to look at $2^1+1$, $2^2+1$, $2^3+1$, and so on for a while to see whether one can detect a pattern. Maybe one notices that for small odd $n$ the number $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$. Then one can use a calculator to verify that $2^{33}+1$ is divisible by $3$. And then maybe (though this is not asked for) one can show that $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ for all odd $n$.

Comment: I see. And maybe you could link something I could hold on to? I've been googling for a solid amount of time today just for this problem, and everything I found was a lot easier :( Thanks for your interest!

Comment: At what stage are you in mathematics? The answer would very much depend on that.

Comment: I'm 16 years old, about to start the 12th grade. In Europe, if that matters.

Comment: Maybe you are just expected to note that the remainders when $2^n$ is divided by $3$ alternate between $1$ and $2$. Or else you can use the fact that if $n$ is odd then $x^n+y^n=(x+y)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}$. Let $x=2$, $y=1$, $n=33$. Then $x+y$, that is, $3$, divides $x^n+y^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of cubes factorization is $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

Setting $a = 2^{11}$ and $b = 1$ yields $2^{33}+1 = (2^{11}+1)(2^{22}-2^{11}+1)$.

Both factors are clearly greater than $1$.